# Perform apply function in multiple column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am trying to find rows where none of the three actors' Facebook likes should be less than half of the other two.
[image]

But i am getting an error **KeyError: 'actor_1_facebook_likes'**.Could you please help me with this.

Comment: I think you need `popular_trio.apply(get_correct_trio, axis=1)`

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to show you a much cleaner and performant way that you can write the code. Create the conditions and use `~` to drop the rows that meet those conditions. I hope this helps:

```
a1 = popular_trio['actor_1_facebook_likes']
a2 = popular_trio['actor_2_facebook_likes']
a3 = popular_trio['actor_3_facebook_likes']

c1 = (a1/2) < a2
c2 = (a2/2) < a1
c3 = (a3/2) < a2
c4 = (a1/2) < a3
c5 = (a2/2) < a3
c6 = (a3/2) < a1

popular_trio[~(c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6)] # or try popular_trio[~((c1)|(c2)|(c3)|(c4)|(c5)|(c6))]
```

Comment: @jezrael yes, I know. I just couldn't help myself to clean up the code ;)